# asynchronous http call request before another function in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I want to accomplish this task base when user click save button from UI component. The save method call the service to accomplished in the following order.

1. Add additional information to data pass from UI. One of the information is get geolocation(lng+lat) information base on ui data. I'm using another service, which makes an HTTP call to Google maps API

   ```
   getLocation(address: string): Location {
       const urlPath = GoogleMapAPI.url + "json?address=" + encodeURIComponent(address) + "&key=" + GoogleMapAPI.key;
       let location: Location = null;

       //console.log(urlPath);
       const results = this.http
         .get(urlPath)
         .map(res => res.json());

       results.subscribe(result => {
         if (result.status !== "OK") { throw new Error("unable to geocode address"); }
         //let location = new Location();
         location = new Location();
         location.address = result.results[0].formatted_address;
         location.latitude = result.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
         location.longitude = result.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
         //console.log("GeocodingService:geocode", address, location);
       });
       return location;
   }
   ```
2. Save the data

   ```
   addRace(race: Race): firebase.Promise<any> {
       race.created_ts = race.updated_ts = moment().format();
       // additional information 
       this.setRaceInfo(race);
       // get geo location
       let location = this.geoService.getLocation(Race.formatFullAddress(race));
       if (location != null){
         race.latitude = location.latitude;
         race.longitude = location.longitude;
         race.address = location.address;
       }
       //save
       return this.racesList.push(race);
   }
   ```

Console log output

```
save Object {name: "Test", date: "2014-11-07", city: "New York", country: "United States"…}
GeocodingService:geocode New York, New York, United States Location {address: "New York, NY, USA", latitude: 40.7127837, longitude: -74.0059413}
```

I'm able to save the data but I couldn't get the geolocation data before the save method is called. The geolocation value return after the save method is called. Am I missing something?

Comment: That is precisely what's supposed to happen, this is the whole point of asynchronous control flows like observables. If you want the value from the HTTP call, you need to subscribe to it *outside* the service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Return data directly from an Observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867020/angular-2-return-data-directly-from-an-observable)

Comment: Are you using observables? Where does the Location object comes from?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Within geolocation funtion, which is part of http call, I do not want to return the observables of the result, and I want to return the value of the result, so I subscribed the http within the same function to get value. Is it wrong approached?

Comment: @Aravind. I'm not returning observables from http call. The location objects return from getLocation function, which return the location object base on address input string.

Comment: why are instantiating location object.

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. You can't do that, *because it's asynchronous*. You have to return an observable or promise of the eventual value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'll try to implement it the way you suggest it. I'll let you know how it goes. Thank you