# Angular Shared Service - Subscribe passes undefined to component

Tags: angular

I am attempting to implement the singleton design pattern by using a shared service so that all components are able to receive the updated global variable provided by the service.

The result is that it will update without issue when called from app component, but no component receives the value when subcribing to:

```
colorString$ = this.colorSource.asObservable();
```

The method used to subscribe which is not returning a value:

```
  constructor( private sharedSer : SharedColorService ) {
    sharedSer.Update(this.myColor);
  }
```

This is the service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }   from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedColorService {

  // Observable string source
private colorSource = new Subject<string>();

// Observable string stream
colorString$ = this.colorSource.asObservable();

// Service message commands

Update(input:string) {
   this.colorSource.next(input);
   console.log("Service Color: " + input);
}
}
```

This is the app.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedColorService} from './sharedColor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  colors = ["#31b0d5", "#d55631", "#d531b0", "#31d556"]
  myColor = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.colors.length)];

  constructor( private sharedSer : SharedColorService ) {
    console.log("I can log");
    console.log("App Color: " + this.myColor);
    sharedSer.Update(this.myColor);
  }
  }
```

This is the component which the app component loads:

app.component.html:

```
<h1>APP: {{myColor}}</h1>
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
```

navigation.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedColorService} from '../sharedColor.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css'],
})

export class NavigationComponent{
  myColor: string;
  errors;
  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedColorService){
    console.log("I AM TRYING TO SUBSCRIBE");
    this._sharedService.colorString$.subscribe(
     result => {
        console.log('Navigation received result: ', result);
        this.myColor = result;
      });
        console.log('Navigation after subscribe: ', this.myColor)
  }
}
```

And finally I have a router outlet, which loads from navigation:

navigation.component.html

```
<a class="col-sm-2" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

about.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedColorService} from '../sharedColor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

myColor: string;
constructor(private _sharedService: SharedColorService){}

ngOnInit() {
  this._sharedService.colorString$.subscribe(
    data => {
      this.myColor = data;
          console.log("About received color: " + this.myColor + " Data: " + data );
    });
}
}
```

The output of console with all of the logging when loading the page is:

```
I can log
app.component.ts:15 App Color: #31d556
sharedColor.service.ts:16 Service Color: #31d556
navigation.component.ts:15 I AM TRYING TO SUBSCRIBE
navigation.component.ts:21 Navigation after subscribe:  undefined
```

When accessing about, it is not called to subscribe either - I don't yet understand the lifecycle of the router outlet regarding OnInit and its constructors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Return data directly from an Observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867020/angular-2-return-data-directly-from-an-observable)

Comment: Also note that you subscribe after the value has been changed, but a vanilla `Subject` won't replay old values to new subscribers.

Comment: Thanks for the link, BehaviorSubject works.

Comment: Same question was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380895/angular-subscription-gets-undefined-after-re-initializing-component/67381088?noredirect=1#comment119099984_67381088

Answer (score 0):

It now works using a Behavior Subject instead of a subject:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }  from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedColorService {

  // Observable string source
private colorSource: BehaviorSubject<string>= new BehaviorSubject<string>("#d55631");

// Observable string stream
colorString$ = this.colorSource.asObservable();

// Service message commands
Update(input:string) {
   this.colorSource.next(input);
   console.log("Service Color: " + input);
}

}
```

Console.log

```
app.component.ts:14 I can log
app.component.ts:15 App Color: #31b0d5
sharedColor.service.ts:17 Service Color: #31b0d5
navigation.component.ts:13 I AM TRYING TO SUBSCRIBE
navigation.component.ts:16 Navigation received result:  #31b0d5
navigation.component.ts:19 Navigation after subscribe:  #31b0d5
core.es5.js:3025 Angular is running in the development mode. Call 
about.component.ts:18 About received color: #31b0d5 Data: #31b0d5
```