# Type Script Get sychronous data from server

Tags: angular, typescript, http-get

I have a problem with control flow in my method. How can I wait for data from the server?Is it possible to prepare data in constructor of service, and get it in singleton in all Components after inject?

```
import { Permission } from '../_models/Permission';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService, AppHttpService } from '../_services/index';
import { RequestActionType } from '../_models/RequestActionType';


@Injectable()
export class PermissionService {

    private getUrl: string = "/Permission/GetAllPermissions";
    private permissions: Permission[] = [];

    constructor(private httpService: AppHttpService, private authService: AuthService) {

        this.PreparePermissionData();
    }

    public PreparePermissionData() {
        if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
            this.httpService.authGet(this.getUrl).then(response => {
                this.permissions = response.Data as Permission[];
            });
        }
```

Comment: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Return data directly from an Observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867020/angular-2-return-data-directly-from-an-observable)

Comment: Also there's a whole section in the tutorial about getting data over HTTP (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: take a look at my angular concepts repo hope that helps you in some of the issues - https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'

 export class MyService {
   private getUrl:string = "/Data/GetData"
   constructor(private http: Http) { }

   public DoSomething(){
     let myData = [];

     this.http.get(this.getUrl).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.somethingWithData(data)
     });

  } 
  public somethingWithData(data) {
    //do anything here with data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to prepare data in constructor of service, and get it in singleton in all Components after inject?