# How to get return values from http post method in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where I need to make a http post method request to a Web API i.e. save some data entered by the user. The Web API would return some values as a result and this result would be used for some UI logic.

I tried making the http post in synchronous way, but it doesn't work properly as expected.

Angular2 component calls this service to save the data:-

```
public SaveCubeReport(userName: any, cubeReport: CubeReportViewModel, APIServiceURL: any)
    {
        var result = this.SaveData(userName, cubeReport, APIServiceURL).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
            });

        console.log(result);
}
```

Http post method call is as follows:-

```
SaveData(userName: any, cubeReport: CubeReportViewModel, APIServiceURL: any)
{
    var temp = this._http.post(APIServiceURL, JSON.stringify(cubeReport), { headers: ContentHeaders })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .do(() => {
            console.log('request finished');
        });
    return res;
}
```

Parent component where the angular2-modal popup is invoked.

```
var dialog = this.modal.open(SaveCubeReport, overlayConfigFactory(
{
    ReportName: this.ReportItem.rpt_name,
    ReportDescription: this.ReportItem.rpt_description,
    Application: this.ReportItem.application_name,
    Owner: this.ReportItem.owner,
    CubeId: this.CubeId,
    ReportId: this.ReportItem.rpt_id,
    ReportJson: JSON.stringify(this.getState())
}, BSModalContext));

dialog
.then((d) => d.result)
.then((r) => {
    // success
    console.log("Dialog ended with success: ", r);
    this.RefreshReportListDropdown(r);
}, (error) => {
    // failure 
    console.log("Dialog ended with failure: ", error);
});
```

function from where the service call is made

```
RefreshReportListDropdown(savedReportName: any)
{
    this._ClientAPIService.GetCubeReportsListByCubeWithEmptyRecord(this._SessionService.LoggedInUser, this._SessionService.SelectedApplication, this.cubeName, this._SessionService.ClientAPIServiceURL)
        .subscribe(
        (res) => {
            this.cubeReportList = res; //This result should contain all records including the recently saved data from the popup
            ....
        }
    );
}
```

All my request are made a asynch requests i.e. it doesn't wait to get the return values.
What is the mistake here?

Comment: Result is a subscription, not the returned value. Please read up on async generally and RxJS specifically, or you'll have a hard time of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Return data directly from an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867020/angular-2-return-data-directly-from-an-observable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the result of http.post call in the `SaveData` method.

```
SaveData(userName: any, cubeReport: CubeReportViewModel, APIServiceURL: any)
{
    return this._http.post(APIServiceURL, JSON.stringify(cubeReport), { headers: ContentHeaders })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .do(() => {
            console.log('request finished');
        });
}
```

After this your `subscribe` in your consumer component will work correctly.

Comment: still it doesn't work correctly or as expected. I am calling this above service while closing a angular2-modal popup. After the record is saved, the modal popup is closed and I need to make a new service to get the list of the records including the recently saved data also and bind a dropdown in the parent component which invoked the popup. But currently it doesn't get the recently saved record in the list? (Please refer the edited question)

Comment: Do you have any sample, for example, in Plunker so that I can see the issue in action?

Comment: It works fine now, was my mistake. Earlier I was calling SaveCubeReport method which was like a extra wrapper in-between the angular2 component and the api service call. But when I removed this and directly call SaveData() method from my angular2 component it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

loginservice.ts :

```
  checklogin(user) {   
   return this.http.post("API_URL",user).map(resp => resp.json());
  }
```

logincomponent.ts :

```
   localvariable={} // or whatever u want 

   customFunction () {
     this.loginservice.checklogin(this.user).subscribe (data => 
     {this.localvariable=data;}) 

     // results is assigned now to this.localvariable
     //write your logic etc ... 
     }
```