# Observable subscribe timing issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-services

I have a service in my component, this service has a method that returns a string value from the server.

Service:

```
getOrderBarcode(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'barcode/getbarcode')
        // .map(this.extractData);
        .map(res => res as string )
}
```

Component:

```
let barcodeService = this.barcodeService.getOrderBarcode();
debugger;
barcodeService.subscribe(result => order.OrderBarcode = result);
console.log(order.OrderBarcode);
// rest of the logic
```

However, when the `.subscribe` is called it is not binding the value at this point, after debugging I found that it applies the value after executing everything in the class, how can I get around this issue?

UPDATE based on the comments and link to another question

Service method:

```
getSomething(callback: (data) => void) {
    debugger;
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'barcode/getbarcode')
        // .timeout(1000)
        // .map(this.extractData);
        .map(res => res as string)
}
```

Component:

```
let a = this.barcodeService.getSomething((data) => {
    debugger;
    console.log(data);
});
```

This debugger does not get hit...

Comment: That's *exactly what's supposed to happen*. The whole reason you're subscribing and using observables is that **the process is asynchronous**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Return data directly from an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867020/angular-2-return-data-directly-from-an-observable)

Comment: okay thanks for pointing me in the right direction, if i am returning a single value and not a stream, is it a case where i can use a promise here instead?

Comment: Other than it perhaps being a more familiar pattern to you, what do you hope to gain from using promises that can't be done with observables?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend mixing the two, stick with one async paradigm as far as possible. RxJS is built right into Angular, so unless you've a whole bunch of promise-y stuff to interact with I'd lean into observables.

Comment: that is a fair point, just trying to understand, if there is ever a case where promise could be used over an observable

Comment: in the example, the op is returning a value from a service, within an existing service, it is kind of confusing me a little bit. I am trying to do this with a single service, however I cannot get it to work

Comment: @jonrsharpe please check the update

Comment: You never `.subscribe` to the observable... Also you clearly never actually use that callback in the method it's passed to; your IDE may already be telling you that.

Comment: the IDE is not throwing any errors, i do not understand where to do the subscribe in the component or the service?

Comment: That depends what functionality you need. In this case, if you need the returned value in the component, that's where you subscribe. JetBrains IDEs show redundant, unused parameters in grey with a squiggly underline, for example.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code, however, I subsrcibed in the component, and still did not get the returned value

Answer (score -1):

Your sample code

```
barcodeService.subscribe(result => order.OrderBarcode = result);
console.log(order.OrderBarcode);
```

## Fix

Use `toPromise` and await the result (or use `then`).

More: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html

Comment: why would somebody convert an observable to promise just for debugging? Thats just overhead. The do operator is meant for this

Comment: thanks, I did wonder about this however I would sceond that opinion as mention above. Could you expand a little?