# Angular 4 HttpClient Observable

Tags: angular

I have a Authenticate Class with I would like to return a true or false but with Observable it is async so I am a lost on how to wait for the httpclient to finish.

At the moment the call to isLogin will always return false.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient , HttpHeaderResponse, HttpHeaders,  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

class LoginData {
    UserKey: string;
    Password: string;
}

class TokenData {
    token: string;
    datetime: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class Authenticate {

private Url  = 'http://192.168.1.1:6000';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public  isLogin(userkey: string, password: string ): boolean {
    const logindata = new LoginData();
        logindata.UserKey = userkey;
        logindata.Password = password;
    const retval = false;
     this.http.post<TokenData>(`${this.Url}/login`, logindata, {headers: this.getHeader()});
         .subscribe(sub => {
        if(sub.token)
        {
            localStorage.setItem('token',sub.token);
            retval = true;
        }
    } );
         return retval;
    }


}
```

Comment: what's `sub` your callback return?

Comment: my subscription on the app.component.ts is this.auth.isLogin('smith', 's12367').subscribe(s => { 
        localStorage.setItem('token', s.token);
   
        this.route.navigateByUrl('/mainpage');
       },
        err => { console.log('Error: ' + err); } );

Comment: I mean what’s the data return.

Comment: Maybe the const keyword is making it unable to modify. Try removing const for retval and see. just a thought!!

Comment: changing it to let also does not work.  What i need is for the http.get to get me the data then I store it in local storage then I return a true of false.  I am trying not to use promise.

Comment: Did you check the token in your browser's local storage?

Comment: A promise is a better fit for this. It returns the value only after the async is complete

Comment: @Z.Bagley, looks like you have shown me the light.        const retpromise =   this.http.post<TokenData>(`${this.Url}/login`, logindata, {headers: this.getHeader()})
         .map(m => {
                     console.log('Got Token Data');
                     localStorage.setItem('token', m.token);
                     return true;
        })
       .toPromise();
       return retpromise;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Return data directly from an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867020/angular-2-return-data-directly-from-an-observable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in a synchronous way in javascript. You have to change your code in the caller of *isLogin*. There is no other way than to implement some kind of callback. Maybe the *async* and *await* keywords will help:

- Change the signature of the isLogin to  *public async isLogin(userkey: string, password: string ): Promise <boolean>*.
- Inside of isLogin use the *toPromise()*. Something like *this.http.post<TokenData>(bla bla).toPromise().then(tokenData => {if(tokenData.token){return true;} else {return false; })*
- Change sinature of caller to *async* and use *await* keyword: *const isLogin: boolean = await component.isLogin('myname', 'mypwd');*